# Dynamic Method Binding in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

With this code

```
public static void doSomething(Animal arg)
{
...
}
```

Which one of the following is more correct? (They both compile and run fine.) Is there a difference?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Animal fido = new Dog();
doSomething(fido);
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Dog fido = new Dog();
doSomething(fido);
}
```

I don't believe it matters, but is one more conventional? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your use of this object later in the code, if this might hold other `Animal` in the rest of the code, then keep it `Animal`, for the call to this method (`doSomething`), it doesn't matter (since a `Dog` **is an** `Animal`).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your use case. If you need to access the semantics of `Dog`, then you should use `Dog`, if you only need the semantics of `Animal`, and you want the generality of `Animal`, you should use `Animal`.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, I like to keep types as general as possible - it is a form of information hiding. Even when a type is only used internally to a class or method, keeping the type general reduces the number of things you have to think about when an instance of that type is referenced later in the code.